# Android Fragments OnCreate vs OnCreateView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

I have a fragment with `OnCreateView` and `onCreate`. In `onCreate()` I download some icons and set the in `ImageView`. The first time the program runs it's ok. The icons are downloaded and set but as soon as I switch tabs and come back `onCreateView()` is called and resets the interface to exactly how is described in the xml file associated.

I was wondering if its possible to stop this thing to happen. Moving the code from `onCreate` to `onCreateView` is not what I want since it just keeps downloading the icons again and again.

`Fragment`

```
public class LiveGameTab1Fragment extends Fragment {


  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View V = inflater.inflate(R.layout.live_game_tab1, container, false);
    return V;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    //download an icon from the internet
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(icon.getIcon(), 0, icon.getIcon().length);
    Drawable iconDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
    imgButton.setImageDrawable(iconDrawable);
  }
}
```

`FragmentActivity`

```
public class LiveGameStats extends FragmentActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_live_game_stats);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.liverealtabcontent, new LiveGameTab1Fragment()).commit();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.liverealtabcontent2, new LiveGameTab2Fragment()).commit();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.liverealtabcontent3, new LiveGameTab3Fragment()).commit();

    }

    FragmentTabHost mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(R.id.liveGameTabhost);
    mTabHost.setup(LiveGameStats.this, getSupportFragmentManager(), android.R.id.tabcontent);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("You"),
            LiveGameTab1Fragment.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("Your Team"),
            LiveGameTab2Fragment.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab3").setIndicator("Your Enemies"),
            LiveGameTab3Fragment.class, null);


  }
}
```

`live_game_tab1.xml`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  tools:context=".DeviceFragment">

  <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/champBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/button_shape_champ"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

`activity_live_game_stats.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/activity_live_game_stats"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
  tools:context="lucian.leagueassistant.activity.LiveGameStats">


  <android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/liveGameTabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />

          <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />


          <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/liverealtabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
          <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/liverealtabcontent2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
          <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/liverealtabcontent3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

**UPDATE**

Read the comments for the right answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry if the code looks out of line I'm answering from my phone

```
    public class LiveGameTab1Fragment extends Fragment {
            Bitmap bitmap;
            Drawable iconDrawable;

            public LiveGameTab1Fragment() {} 

            public LiveGameTab1Fragment(Context context
             //add this if you need something from resources) {
//I don't know what you mean by icon.getIcon()
                bitmap =  BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(icon.getIcon(), 0, icon.getIcon().length);

                iconDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), bitmap);
            }

              @Override
              public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                View V = inflater.inflate(R.layout.live_game_tab1, container, false);
                return V;
              }

              @Override //you need the onViewCreated function again I'm on my phone so I might be wrong about the variables inside so make sure to take the right code and the functions inside
              public void onViewCreated(View v) {
                super.onViewCreated(v);
                //code moved to constructor so the image is initialize only ones 


                 ImageButton imgButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.yourButtonId);

                 imgButton.setImageDrawable(iconDrawable);
              }
            }
```

Comment: No it's not take a close look

Comment: You should not override the non default constructor of Fragments

Comment: I agree with you but Android studio will propose a fix I'm on my phone so I don't remember the proper way but in general it will do the job

Comment: You don't need to pass a Context object to a Fragment anyway, so I'm not sure what this answer is suggesting

Comment: You do because it's not yet created so at that state you don't have context

Comment: You can call `getActivity()` or `view.getContext()`... There's really no need to pass any Context objects

Comment: Both are null ate that state the view will be available after create view and activity after onAttach

Comment: OnCreate and onCreateView are after onAttach, last time I checked

Comment: But not before constructor and that's when I'm using context

Comment: Sorry if I answered so late. I had to get some sleep. `icon.getIcon` is a method from a class i made. it returns a `byte[]` array that can be turned into a bitmap.This icon is downloaded from the a rest service. Anyway I tried your way. `public void onViewCreated(View v, Bundle bundle)` I putted the code that downloads and sets icons but still I get the raw xml layout

Comment: What do you mean by raw XML layout?

Comment: unmodified xml. `inflater.inflate(R.layout.live_game_tab1, container, false);`. `live_game_tab1.xml`. My icons also seem that they didnt even downloaded **EDIT** also android suggest that I should use the default constructor with `Fragment#setArguments(bundle)`

Comment: If you're downloading image from the internet I would suggest you to use Glide or Picasso and not deal with that yourself and also when you use tabs use tabLayout and view pager try using one of them and notify me

Comment: I had some problems with view pager but now it works fine. Thanks I'll mark this as corect

Comment: Awesome glad to help